# History of changes for a loopback model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I am having a trouble to find a solution to this problem. I have an AthleteProfile persisted model which has one to one relation with Athlete. AthleteProfile model has height, weight, and body fat percentage properties.

The problem here is, I should be able to get all changes throughout the time and also I should be able to get latest athlete profile with "get" method.

Is it a good practice to create a history table for that? Or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already separated your Athlete profile from your athlete table, you could use it as a one-to-many relation (from athlete to AthleteProfile) with timestamps. Then for the current profile you just get the latest...